# Can't use certain colors in Windows 8 HTML5 app

Tags: css, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

For some reason, when I set the background color in a Windows 8 app to either `#0D0D0D` or `#EEEEEE` it displays as `#111111` or `#F2F2F2` respectively.

Is this a bug, or is there a reason for this? It seems fine for random other colors, but for some reason when I set it to something between black and white it demands that it changes. I've tried switching to RGB colors, too, and it still isn't working.

It's really not that big of a deal, but I'm a perfectionist and it's frustrating that the colors are just slightly off of my designs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the same occur if you use the three-character form (where possible), such as `#eee` instead of `#eeeeee`? It *should* (depending on what the problem is), I'm just curious if whatever's happening only happens under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yep, doesn't matter if it's 6 or 3 characters.

Comment: how are you determining that it's using a different color than what you specified?  I'm not seeing any issues here, using those two colors.  A color picker from a third-party app is reporting exactly what was specified in the CSS. What color-depth are you running on your computer, if 24-bit color I don't think you should be seeing this behavior.

Comment: I was also able to make an app with these background colors without problems.  Furthermore, asker has accepted an obviously-wrong claim as the correct answer.  It is my belief that this question reflects simple confusion on the asker's part.  (For example, they might have set the alpha of the layer and be seeing the base white through it, or something.)

Comment: Could you give some more details about how you're setting these colors? It's hard to fix a problem you can't duplicate, especially when it doesn't make much sense on the face of it.

Comment: Have you got some code or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue, what i did is to change hex value into rgb or if it is exact color name i apply that name to hex value. you can find many online color converters online. hope this helps.